# Test in docker-selenium can download file when running locally but not on Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

Using ruby, capybara, docker-selenium:3.141.59-zirconium,

```
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(chromeOptions: { 
args: %w[--ignore-certificate-errors --window-size=1360,998] })

Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
            Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :remote, 
                                                url: 'http://selenium:4444/wd/hub',
                                                desired_capabilities: capabilities)
```

end

Test clicks on 'Download'.

Locally file is downloaded to selenium container, but on Jenkins, it doesn't.
Selenium and chrome driver version is the same.
The only difference is the docker version (docker 18.09.6, docker-compose 1.24.0 on Jenkins and 19 and 25 locally).
docker-selenium container logs have no useful information, same as browser console log.

What could be the reason, what should I look for?

Comment: Did you checked the download folder (mapped if any in script) manually to confirm the download is unsuccessful?

Comment: sure, I checked _/home/seluser/Downloads_; and also searched with find command from root - it's not there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update `/home/seluser/Downloads` in order to write to it.
Or download to `/tmp` instead